# Separation of variables restrict solutions for PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

When solving a partial differential equation (PDE) using separation of variables, it is assumed that the solution to the PDE is the product of functions of each variable. For examle, given:

$$ \psi (x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$$

In what type of PDEs is this valid?

How can we know that no solutions are being 'ignored' by making this assumption?

Are there any cases in which we can be sure that all the solutions can be written as the product of functions?

Comment: Not all solutions will be of this form, even under the best of circumstances. You'll need boundary conditions, and you'll need to form sums of such solutions either as discrete sums and/or using integrals over parameter(s).

Comment: We know that an infinity of solutions are ignored by making this assumption. The general solution of a PDE (without specified boundary condition) involves one or several arbitrary function of the variables.